# Create multiple entrypoint in python setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py

Currently my setup.py looks like this:

```
   setup(
        name="package",
        entry_points={
            'console_scripts': [
                'package = src.utils:main'
            ],
            },
        install_requires=["docopt",],
    )
```

I am able to run my package like `package --arg1 arg --arg2 arg`. And it runs `src.utils:main`.

But how can I have another argument that can run another method,

Like `package --arg3 arg`. If the parameter arg3 is detected, I would like to run another script  `src.utils:sub_main`